# Manjaro 21.0.1 download links are broken!

Tags: manjaro, download

I'm trying to download Manjaro on my system but all of the links on the website are broken. is it the same for you?

EDIT: I upgraded the Manjaro Gnome version as always. I was on a stable branch and after the update, the Gnome version updated to 40 and the Gnome shell stayed at 38.
and after that, the whole Gnome crashed. now I want to install Manjaro KDE and all of the links are broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download links seem to have an error in them. On the [download page for the KDE version](https://manjaro.org/downloads/official/kde/), the download link is:

```
https://download.manjaro.org/kde/21.0.1/manjaro-kde-21.0.1-210410-linux510.iso/download
```

If you remove the `/download` from the end, the link seems to work correctly:

https://download.manjaro.org/kde/21.0.1/manjaro-kde-21.0.1-210410-linux510.iso

Comment: thank you soooo much. I really needed it. God bless you

Comment: The best way to thank for a successful answer on StackExchange is to click the green checkmark to the left of the answer, to mark is as accepted. Only the writer of the original question can do that, and it's even better than a regular upvote.